# Ionic 4 Image Picker Crashing android app

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using ionic image picker to select multiple image and upload to firestore storage. But the plugin cordova image picker is crashing my android app. I saw a tutorial and done a poc. Plugin is wokring fine in poc . but when i implement it in my app it is crashing. Im stuck for more then one week. Please anyone help me with working solution.

```
alert('hello')
this.images = [];

var options = {
  maximumImagesCount: 3,
  outputType: 1
}
    this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then(async (results) => {
    alert('Image URI: ');

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + results[i];

    }
     (err) => {
    //   // Handle error
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    alert('hello'+err)
  })
```

Comment: What's the output of `err`?

Comment: check your Console if you are getting any error.

Comment: There is no error at all . It just coming out of the app like crashing message i received @rzp

Comment: I am not getting any error. Simply it just coming out of the app like i have been receiving crashing message @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: Run AndroidStudio and see logs on Logcat, should be something there when the app crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use**

```
* `cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release`
* `ioinc cordova platform rm android`
* `ionic cordova platform add android`
* `ionic cordova build android`
```

Answer (score 4):

1. **Install cordova plugin** :
   **command**:- cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release

   2.**Remove Platform** :
   **command**:- Ionic cordova platform rm android

   3.**Add Platform** :
   **command**:- ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0

   4.**build project** :
   **command**:- ionic cordova build android

   Tested Ok on android platform version 8.0.0

Comment: Oh my god! This solved my problem after hours of debugging. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Install plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker --variable PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="App wants to access your gallery"
```

Install Dependency:

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/image-picker
```

Use Below Mentioned Function to get images.

```
getPictures() {
      this.imagePicker.getPictures({
        maximumImagesCount: 5,
        outputType: 1
      }).then(selectedImg => {
        selectedImg.forEach(i => this.images.push("data:image/jpeg;base64," + i));
      })
    }
```